# Dynamically Added ng-model in custom directive does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I have searched for this question on Stackoverflow, but all are different from this one. Although the question might be the same the implementation is different.

This directive accepts an array of JSON called config. Which contains properties of an input or a dropdown. I also receive the variable that has to be binded within ngModel. Everything works fine like ng-maxlength ng-minlength but `ng-model` does not. I cannot fetch the values or in simple words there is no two way binding. Also to get all the values within  a single object I append a string called pgCard within the `name` attribute in the custom directive. To make it look like `pgCard.*` to use it directly as a json object. But all in vain. I even tried removing the `pgCard` but of no use.

Below is my custom directive Element markup

```
<program-gateway config="configArrayCard" name="pgCard"></program-gateway>
```

This is my custom directive.

```
app.directive('programGateway',['$compile',
                                        function($compile){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace :true,
        template:"<div class='row'></div>",
        scope:{
            config:"=",
            name:"@"
        },
        link: function(scope,e,attr){
            var modelPrefix=scope.name+"." || "";

            var field="",model="";

            var max="",min="",maxlen="",req="",options="";

            var leftHTML="",rightHTML="",innerHTML="";

            scope.config=sortByKey(scope.config,"propertyKey");

            angular.forEach(scope.config,function(value,key){
                model=modelPrefix+value.propertyKey;
                var midLen=(Math.floor(scope.config.length/2))+(Math.floor(scope.config.length%2));
                if(!value.propertyInfo.selection){
                    if(value.propertyInfo.hasOwnProperty("max")){
                        max="data-ng-maxlength='"+value.propertyInfo.max+"'";
                        maxlen="maxlength='"+value.propertyInfo.max+"'"
                    } if(value.propertyInfo.hasOwnProperty("min")){
                        min="data-ng-minlength='"+value.propertyInfo.min+"'";
                    }
                    req=(value.propertyInfo.optional)?"":"required";
                    field="<input "+req+" class='form-control' type='text' id='"+model+"' data-ng-model='"+model+"' "+max+" "+min+" "+maxlen+">";
                }else{
                     var optArr="[\""+(value.propertyInfo.selectionOptions).replace(/,/g, '","')+"\"]";
                    field="<select data-ng-options='opt for opt in "+optArr+"' "+req+" data-ng-model='"+model+"' class='form-control' id='"+model+"'>"+
                            "<option value=''>Select </option>"+
                          "</select>";
                }
                if(key<midLen){
                    leftHTML+="<div class='form-group'>"+
                                    "<label for='"+value.propertyInfo.propertyLabel+"' class='col-sm-5 control-label'><span data-ng-hide='"+value.propertyInfo.optional+"' class='red'>*</span>"+value.propertyInfo.propertyLabel+":</label>"+
                                    "<div class='col-sm-7'>"
                                        +field+
                                    "</div>"+
                                "</div>";
                }else{
                    rightHTML+="<div class='form-group'>"+
                                    "<label for='"+value.propertyInfo.propertyLabel+"' class='col-sm-5 control-label'><span data-ng-hide='"+value.propertyInfo.optional+"' class='red'>*</span>"+value.propertyInfo.propertyLabel+":</label>"+
                                    "<div class='col-sm-7'>"
                                        +field+
                                    "</div>"+
                                "</div>";
                }//if closed
            });// for closed
            innerHTML="<div class='col-sm-6'>"+leftHTML+"</div>"+
                      "<div class='col-sm-6'>"+rightHTML+"</div>";
            e.html(innerHTML);
            scope.$watch(function() {
                 return scope.pgCard = scope.pgCard;  
             });
            $compile(e.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

This is the snap of the json that I receive

```
"config":[{"propertyKey":"reportGroup","editable":true,"propertyInfo"
:{"max":3,"optional":true,"propertyLabel":"Report Group","selection":false}},{"propertyKey":"sendStatementToCompany"
,"propertyValue":"Yes","editable":true,"propertyInfo":{"optional":false,"propertyLabel":"Send Statement
 to Company","selection":true,"selectionOptions":"Yes,No","defaultValue":"Yes"}}]
```

Please help am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Scale this down to  minimal representation of the model problem and create a demo that reproduces it

Comment: Most likely an issue that `pgCard` is not in your isolated scope.

Comment: I can't,  since the whole code is required to undestand the problem. Altough I can higlight or seperate the part that is not working

Comment: Also your `$watch` doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl pgCard is somthing that I have already declared and instantiated as $scope.pgCrad={}; SO should be accessible as $scope.pgCrad.<property in ngModel>

Comment: can't you just add a require:'^ngModel' on your directive and interact with ngModelCtrl ?

Comment: But that is in controller , right? Directive has isolated scope

Comment: @Walfrat I'm a new bee and don't know much about custom directives. Also the topic is quite complex to understand this early.

Comment: @ charlietfl Yes. So what to do now to enable two way binding and getting the value in a single json object

Comment: Should I make scope my directive isolated to public scope. Will that help.